# spark executor vs instances vs cores vs cpus

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

My question can be naive and since i am not able to find any explanation over web and SO which can explain in simple enough to understand for a beginner that's why posting this question.

Can anyone help me understand what's the difference b/w spark executor vs instances vs cores vs cpus?
OR
more formally "spark.executor.instances" vs "spark.executor.cores" vs "spark.task.cpus"

Please guide me or atleast point me to any resource which can explain these things in simpler manner to a starter

Answer (score 0):

Simply put,
`spark.executor.instances` is the number of executors you want in your Spark Application.
`spark.executor.cores` is the number of cores you want in each of your executors. You can think of these as individual threads in the same process(executor) that are capable of processing a `Task`

So, when your spark app runs, you can have a total of `spark.executor.instances x spark.executor.cores` workers, working together, in parallel, on the tasks.